# Helloworld Doesn't run on Emulator

Tags: java, android, adk

Okay, this is really ticking me off. I ran it on both my emulator and on an android device. The code does NOT display "Helloworld, Android -mykong.com". I start the app, find it on the emulator, click on it, and it goes to interface of the app. However, it is just a blank screen! This error is not an issue of me finding the app, its not with the emulator or the android phone, the issue has to lie either in the code or in the way the code is structured/built.  I know the the helloworld code is 100% correct because its from a reputable tutorial site. These are my three pairs of code. Please help, I am in desperate need!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test123"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test123.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test123;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void activity()
    {
    Intent helloWorld = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HelloWorldjavaactivity.class );
    startActivity( helloWorld );
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

HelloWorldjavaactivity.java

```
package com.example.test123;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloWorldjavaactivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Hello World, Android - mkyong.com");
        setContentView(text);
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file! By default you will see MainActivity!

Comment: Either you miss something or the code is not correct. You get blank because in the manifest you probably has MainActivity as the LAUNCHER, if you change to HelloWorldjavaactivity your app will crash. Anyway post your manifest.

Comment: I added it, please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not starting the HelloWorldjavaactivity.java activity. You need something like the following in your MainActivity:

```
Intent helloWorld = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HelloWorldjavaactivity.class );
startActivity( helloWorld );
```

Of course, you need that code to be triggered by some even, a button press for example.

It would be easier to just eliminate the second activity (since your MainActivity isn't doing anything anyway) and put the code in your MainActivity instead. You'll also need to edit the layout for your MainActivity so that it includes the appropriate views.

Comment: Not good even though it works! Thats not necessary because he can do it from the manifest file.

Comment: That's very true, and much simpler! But wouldn't it be better for him to put that code in the MainActivity instead of in a second activity that's totally unnecessary? Where is this trusted tutorial site that's giving such bad examples?

Comment: Good point! I guess he is confused in case the second activity is necessary.

Comment: Wait I am quite confused. I should place that line of code in the MainActivity. I never understood why there was a MainActivity and Activity_main and manifest file. If they can all do the same thing, why not just one?

Comment: MainActivity is a .java file, which contains java code. activity_main is an .xml file which contains layout information. It decides where the UI elements are on the screen, UI elements which you control through MainActivity. The part of manifest that deals with MainActivity is just stating that MainActivity is the initial activity to launch. If you change MainActivity to some other activity, that activity will be the first activity launched when the application is opened.

Comment: okay, thank you! I won't be able to test it out until tomorrow. One last question, in my MainActivity file,would I make a new method for activities or would I put it under the Oncreate method?

Comment: If I read it correctly, you want to know where you should be starting activities other than your MainActivity? Or are you asking about functions that your MainActivity uses?

Comment: Well I figured that code needed to be in MainActivity. I was asking specifically about the functions/methods that mainactivity uses and where I should put that line of code.

Comment: Most commonly, outside of OnCreate(), but inside of the MainActivity class.

Comment: Sorry another question. When I do that I get errors saying no return type, syntax error insert "}" to complete method body.

Comment: Looks like you're specifying a return type for a method, but you don't have a return statement in it, and also it's missing the closing brace, but without seeing the code, I can't be sure.

Comment: You've got the startActivity() call inside a function called activity(), but you never call that function. You need to call it inside of onCreate(), like so:

`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity();
    }`

Comment: when I run it it on the phone now, it goes to the app, starts, I then get a black screen, and then it says "test123"- the name of my app file, has stopped working.

Comment: We're just running up a huge list of comments here, but we're not really adding much value for other users. Can you access my email address from my profile? If so, send me a copy of the logcat after your app force closes and I'll see what I can do. The sort of questions you're asking, and the problems you're having indicate that you need to do a lot more studying in Java before you try to tackle Android specifically. I'm more than willing to help you out, but the comment area for this question is probably not the best place to do it.